# Does Vagrant introduce another layer between host OS and guest OS

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vagrant

If I use Vagrant, does it introduce another layer of resource users inserting itself between host OS and VM? Does it always run between host OS and VMWare/Vbox? Should I provide for extra RAM / CPU if I plan on using Vagrant to facilitate extra Vagrant processes running together with every VM it starts?

Or is it, in the simplest terms, just a collection of commands that tells VM how to assemble and run itself and there is no Vagrant process running with every VM instance it starts?

**Edit**: this is one question, just split into several questions to better describe the intent. The RAM / CPU question does not relate to running VM's per se, it is just another way of asking if Vagrant itself consumes any extra resources.

Comment: No, no, perhaps, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Vagrant does not introduce another layer of abstraction between Host OS and Guest OS.
With VMWare hypervisor, use of a separate plugin is required to allow Vagrant to communicate with VMware, the plugin uses 6 MB of memory and 0 CPU cycles when idle.

[image]
[image]

Once you open terminal and spin a VM with Vagrant, bash creates a Vagrant subprocess and allocates resources to it, which are very limited.

[image]
[image]
[image]

So while using VM's will require additional resources in terms of CPU and RAM, Vagrant resource usage is negligible.